# Branching points and genus of riemann surface of algebraic function

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

Consider the Riemann surface $N$  of the algebraic function given by

$$  w=   ((z-2)^2 (\sqrt(z) + i))^{\frac{1}{3}} $$

What are the branching points of  S?  What are their orders? What is the genus?

I think the  branching points are $z=2$ and $z= 1$ with orders of $2$ and $1$ respectively? Am I correct in my assessment? Regarding the Riemann surface I know that there is a correspondence between Riemann surfaces and algebraic fuctions. Is the genus of this Riemann surface equal to 1?

Comment: So over $z=r^2$ this would be $w^3=(r^2-2)^2(r+i)$?